# Do they grind up chicks for breakfast omelets?

Tags: zoology, ethics

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2009/09/01/chicks-being-ground-up-al_n_273652.html

This story is on Facebook, about a video showing chicks being ground up to make breakfast omelets. Is this real or some shock media technique?

Comment: Where are you seeing that they are made into omelets?  The story only says they are ground up and a quick bit of research shows that the ground chicks go into dog food or fertilizer.
http://blogs.discovery.com/animal_news/2009/09/horrific-egg-industry-grinds-millions-of-baby-chicks-alive.html

Comment: Putting this on hold until there is a real claim made.